# Jackson Deserialising :com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to deserialise following json into Java object but it is complaining that it is not able to recognise the accesslevel property .Please see below:

```
{
    "Role1": [
        {
            "path": "/1_order/1_general/customer.comp.json",
            "accesslevel": "ENABLED"
        },
        {
            "path": "/1_order/1_general/CustomerComponent.json",
            "accesslevel": "DISABLED"
        },
        {
            "path": "/2_help/DummyComponent.json",
            "accesslevel": "ENABLED"
        }
    ]
}
```

Java object looks like:

```
public class AccessLevelConfigWrapper {

    HashMap<String, List<AccessLevelDetails>> listOfRoles;

    public AccessLevelConfigWrapper() {

    }

    public HashMap<String, List<AccessLevelDetails>> getListOfRoles() {
        return listOfRoles;
    }

    public void setListOfRoles(HashMap<String, List<AccessLevelDetails>> listOfRoles) {
        this.listOfRoles = listOfRoles;
    }

}
```

**AccessLevelDetails:**

```
public class AccessLevelDetails {

    @JsonProperty
    private String accessLevel;
    @JsonProperty
    private String path;

    public String getAccessLevel() {
        return accessLevel;
    }

    public void setAccessLevel(String accessLevel) {
        this.accessLevel = accessLevel;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

}
```

This is how i am trying to deserialise it :

```
TypeReference<HashMap<String, List<AccessLevelDetails>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, List<AccessLevelDetails>>>() {
        };
        this.accessLevelConfigWrapper = new AccessLevelConfigWrapper();
        this.accessLevelConfigWrapper.setListOfRoles(
                (new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSONObject.valueToString(this.parentConfigWithPaths), typeRef)));
```

And i am getting following **exception**:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "accesslevel" (class com.gatcbiotech.blueberry.gateway.authorization.model.AccessLevelDetails), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "accessLevel", "path"])
 at [Source: {"CN=it-soft,CN=Groups,DC=intern,DC=gatc-biotech,DC=com":[{"path":"/1_order/1_general/customer.comp.json","accesslevel":"ENABLED"},{"path":"/1_order/1_general/CustomerComponent.json","accesslevel":"DISABLED"},{"path":"/2_help/DummyComponent.json","accesslevel":"ENABLED"}]}; line: 1, column: 122] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["CN=it-soft,CN=Groups,DC=intern,DC=gatc-biotech,DC=com"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.gatcbiotech.blueberry.gateway.authorization.model.AccessLevelDetails["accesslevel"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:51)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:744)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:915)
    at ....
```

Comment: You have a typo (`accessLevel` vs `accesslevel`). JSON has `accesslevel`, but in annotation you set `accessLevel`.

Comment: @uthark: i dont believe , i spent 1 hour figuring out the solution. Thanks man

Comment: If it works, then mark my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a typo (`accessLevel` vs `accesslevel`). JSON has `accesslevel`, but in annotation you set `accessLevel`. They should match, because jackson is case-sensitive when parsing JSON keys.